# Is it a good idea to limit speed of one motor of twin motor diaphragm pump?

Tags: pumps

I have the below 12V pump. It is a common garden spray pump, China made, no datasheet.
[image]

The thing is this, it is supposed to be a suction pump, but once upon a time, long back, I connected the inlet to a overhead tank and the pump started making strange noises and then didn't work for a short while before starting to work again. I asked someone and the answer was that positive pressure source should not be connected to diaphragm pumps as the diaphragm can start to float. But here's my confusion, since this is basically two pumps in series, isn't the first pump becoming positive pressure source for the second? Why is that not a problem? Secondly, if I attach a speed controller to the second motor/pump and reduce its speed, since this second pump is connected to positive pressure source, would it have any bad effects on the slower second pump?

Comment: Datasheet appears to be mounted to the motor.

Comment: @Abel this image is just for representation, my actual store bought piece has no identification of even the manufacturer, but I guess the same specs apply